# Seeing incoming connections, sockets java

Tags: java, sockets

Currently I use this little snippet of code to get my java server up and allowing connections to it.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000)
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

I was wondering how I can see all connections to my server from the client. Meaning the ip address connected, and everything about the incoming connection.

Thanks

Comment: I was wondering is this your entire code or a snippet. This snippet would work with only 1 client right? U would need to service each client on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time a client connects log the clients ip address etc. on your server, then have the client send a message to the server e.g. "get clients". When the server socket reads this String on the datainputstream send the list of clients and there information back

Comment: I see, and is it possible to disconnect a current user because of their ip adress?

Comment: you can just use socket.close()

Comment: but what if there are 15 ip addresses connected to the server, can I do it for a single one and not all?

Comment: yes, don't close the serverSocket, you want to keep a list of each socket as a client connects (ArrayList is usually easiest) then you would say something like -  for (Socket s:socketArray){ if (s.getInetAddress()==theInetaddressToDelete) s.close;}

Comment: Thanks ghostbust555! Another quick question... are there any reasons that you can think of why i would be able to connect to my server socket from the same network, but not from a different one? (from the same network i use the network IP 192.168..... but from the other network I use the actual internet ip)

Comment: When I do    System.out.println(serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString()); It outputs       
0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: Yes, if you don't port forward your router it will always block incoming connections outside fo the local network. Google port forwarding

Comment: Dont get the server socket address (unless I completely misunderstood the question), you wan't to get the socket address from the Sockets (not ServerSocket)